# Gmail formatting on html template is getting screwed up

Tags: html, email, gmail, html-email

I have created an HTML template by using Mailchimp templates and completely personalized it.

The code is working on all the clients (even Outlook (?!) ) but unfortunately Gmail is driving me crazy.

Could you please give it a look on why it gets all messed up? (It doesn't keep the column template and social icons get pushed to the left).

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <title>Smile.</title>
        <style type="text/css">
        @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato|Roboto&display=swap');
            /* /\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/ CLIENT-SPECIFIC STYLES /\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/ */
            #outlook a{padding:0;} /* Force Outlook to provide a "view in browser" message */
            .ReadMsgBody{width:100%;} .ExternalClass{width:100%;} /* Force Hotmail to display emails at full width */
            .ExternalClass, .ExternalClass p, .ExternalClass span, .ExternalClass font, .ExternalClass td, .ExternalClass div {line-height: 100%;} /* Force Hotmail to display normal line spacing */
            body, table, td, p, a, li, blockquote{-webkit-text-size-adjust:100%; -ms-text-size-adjust:100%;} /* Prevent WebKit and Windows mobile changing default text sizes */
            table, td{mso-table-lspace:0pt; mso-table-rspace:0pt;} /* Remove spacing between tables in Outlook 2007 and up */
            img{-ms-interpolation-mode:bicubic;} /* Allow smoother rendering of resized image in Internet Explorer */
            /* /\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/ RESET STYLES /\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/ */
            body{margin:0; padding:0;}
            img{border:0; height:auto; line-height:100%; outline:none; text-decoration:none;}
            table{border-collapse:collapse !important;}
            body, #bodyTable, #bodyCell{height:100% !important; width:100% !important;}
            /* /\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/ TEMPLATE STYLES /\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/ */
            /* ========== Page Styles ========== */
            #bodyCell{padding:20px;}
            #templateContainer{width:600px !important; max-width: 600px;}
            /**
            * @tab Page
            * @section background style
            * @tip Set the background color and top border for your email. You may want to choose colors that match your company's branding.
            * @theme page
            */
            body, #bodyTable{
                font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
                font-weight: 400;
                line-height: 1.6;
                /*@editable*/ background-color:#ececec;
            }
            /**
            * @tab Page
            * @section background style
            * @tip Set the background color and top border for your email. You may want to choose colors that match your company's branding.
            * @theme page
            */
            #bodyCell{
                /*@editable*/ border-top:4px solid #ffffff;
            }
            /**
            * @tab Page
            * @section email border
            * @tip Set the border for your email.
            */
            #templateContainer{
                /*@editable*/ border:1px solid #fff;
            }
            /**
            * @tab Page
            * @section heading 1
            * @tip Set the styling for all first-level headings in your emails. These should be the largest of your headings.
            * @style heading 1
            */
            h1{
                /*@editable*/ color:#0f0f0f !important;
                display:block;
                /*@editable*/ font-family: 'Roboto', Helvetica, serif;
                /*@editable*/ font-size:26px;
                /*@editable*/ font-style:normal;
                /*@editable*/ font-weight:bold;
                /*@editable*/ line-height:100%;
                /*@editable*/ letter-spacing:normal;
                margin-top:0;
                margin-right:0;
                margin-bottom:10px;
                margin-left:0;
                /*@editable*/ text-align:left;
            }
            /**
            * @tab Page
            * @section heading 2
            * @tip Set the styling for all second-level headings in your emails.
            * @style heading 2
            */
            h2{
                /*@editable*/ color:#0f0f0f !important;
                display:block;
                /*@editable*/ font-family: 'Roboto', Helvetica, serif;
                /*@editable*/ font-size:20px;
                /*@editable*/ font-style:normal;
                /*@editable*/ font-weight:bold;
                /*@editable*/ line-height:100%;
                /*@editable*/ letter-spacing:normal;
                margin-top:0;
                margin-right:0;
                margin-bottom:10px;
                margin-left:0;
                /*@editable*/ text-align:left;
            }
            /**
            * @tab Page
            * @section heading 3
            * @tip Set the styling for all third-level headings in your emails.
            * @style heading 3
            */
            h3{
                /*@editable*/ color:#0f0f0f !important;
                display:block;
                /*@editable*/ font-family: 'Roboto', Helvetica, serif;
                /*@editable*/ font-size:16px;
                /*@editable*/ font-style:italic;
                /*@editable*/ font-weight:normal;
                /*@editable*/ line-height:100%;
                /*@editable*/ letter-spacing:normal;
                margin-top:0;
                margin-right:0;
                margin-bottom:10px;
                margin-left:0;
                /*@editable*/ text-align:left;
            }
            /**
            * @tab Page
            * @section heading 4
            * @tip Set the styling for all fourth-level headings in your emails. These should be the smallest of your headings.
            * @style heading 4
            */
            h4{
                /*@editable*/ color:#0f0f0f !important;
                display:block;
                /*@editable*/ font-family: 'Roboto', Helvetica, serif;
                /*@editable*/ font-size:14px;
                /*@editable*/ font-style:italic;
                /*@editable*/ font-weight:normal;
                /*@editable*/ line-height:100%;
                /*@editable*/ letter-spacing:normal;
                margin-top:0;
                margin-right:0;
                margin-bottom:10px;
                margin-left:0;
                /*@editable*/ text-align:left;
            }
            /* ========== Header Styles ========== */
            /**
            * @tab Header
            * @section preheader style
            * @tip Set the background color and bottom border for your email's preheader area.
            * @theme header
            */
            #templatePreheader{
                /*@editable*/ background-color:#ffffff;
            }
            /**
            * @tab Header
            * @section preheader text
            * @tip Set the styling for your email's preheader text. Choose a size and color that is easy to read.
            */
            .preheaderContent{
                /*@editable*/ color:#0f0f0f;
                /*@editable*/ font-family: 'Roboto', Helvetica, serif;
                /*@editable*/ font-size:12px;
                /*@editable*/ line-height:125%;
                /*@editable*/ text-align:left;
            }
            /**
            * @tab Header
            * @section preheader link
            * @tip Set the styling for your email's preheader links. Choose a color that helps them stand out from your text.
            */
            .preheaderContent a:link, .preheaderContent a:visited, /* Yahoo! Mail Override */ .preheaderContent a .yshortcuts /* Yahoo! Mail Override */{
                /*@editable*/ color:#0f0f0f;
                /*@editable*/ font-weight:normal;
                /*@editable*/ text-decoration:underline;
            }
            /**
            * @tab Header
            * @section header style
            * @tip Set the background color and borders for your email's header area.
            * @theme header
            */
            #templateHeader{
                /*@editable*/ background-color:#ffffff;             
            }
            /**
            * @tab Header
            * @section header text
            * @tip Set the styling for your email's header text. Choose a size and color that is easy to read.
            */
            .headerContent{
                /*@editable*/ color:#0f0f0f;
                /*@editable*/ font-family: 'Lato', Arial, sans-serif;
                /*@editable*/ font-size:18px;
                /*@editable*/ font-weight:bold;
                /*@editable*/ line-height:100%;
                /*@editable*/ padding-top:0;
                /*@editable*/ padding-right:0;
                /*@editable*/ padding-bottom:0;
                /*@editable*/ padding-left:0;
                /*@editable*/ text-align:left;
                /*@editable*/ vertical-align:middle;
            }
            /**
            * @tab Header
            * @section header link
            * @tip Set the styling for your email's header links. Choose a color that helps them stand out from your text.
            */
            .headerContent a:link, .headerContent a:visited, /* Yahoo! Mail Override */ .headerContent a .yshortcuts /* Yahoo! Mail Override */{
                /*@editable*/ color:#0f0f0f;
                /*@editable*/ font-weight:normal;
                /*@editable*/ text-decoration:underline;
            }
            #headerImage{
                height:auto;
                max-width:600px;
            }
            /* ========== Body Styles ========== */
            /**
            * @tab Body
            * @section body style
            * @tip Set the background color and borders for your email's body area.
            */
            #templateBody{
                /*@editable*/ background-color: #ffffff;
                /*@editable*/ border-top:1px solid #FFFFFF;
                /*@editable*/ border-bottom:1px solid #CCCCCC;
            }
            /**
            * @tab Body
            * @section body text
            * @tip Set the styling for your email's main content text. Choose a size and color that is easy to read.
            * @theme main
            */
            .bodyContent{
                /*@editable*/ color:#0f0f0f;
                /*@editable*/ font-family: 'Lato', Arial, sans-serif;
                /*@editable*/ font-size:20px;
                /*@editable*/ line-height:150%;
                padding-top:20px;
                padding-right:20px;
                padding-bottom:20px;
                padding-left:20px;
                /*@editable*/ text-align:left;
            }
            /**
            * @tab Body
            * @section body link
            * @tip Set the styling for your email's main content links. Choose a color that helps them stand out from your text.
            */
            .bodyContent a:link, .bodyContent a:visited, /* Yahoo! Mail Override */ .bodyContent a .yshortcuts /* Yahoo! Mail Override */{
                /*@editable*/ color:#120061;
                /*@editable*/ font-weight:normal;
                /*@editable*/ text-decoration:underline;
            }
            .bodyContent img{
                display:inline;
                height:auto;
                max-width:560px;
            }
            /* ========== Footer Styles ========== */
            /**
            * @tab Footer
            * @section footer style
            * @tip Set the background color and borders for your email's footer area.
            * @theme footer
            */
            #templateFooter{
                /*@editable*/ background-color:#424953;
                /*@editable*/ border-top:1px solid #FFFFFF;
            }
            /**
            * @tab Footer
            * @section footer text
            * @tip Set the styling for your email's footer text. Choose a size and color that is easy to read.
            * @theme footer
            */
            .footerContent{
                /*@editable*/ color:#ffffff;
                /*@editable*/ font-family: 'Lato', Arial, sans-serif;
                /*@editable*/ font-size:15px;
                /*@editable*/ line-height:150%;
                padding-top:20px;
                padding-right:20px;
                padding-bottom:20px;
                padding-left:20px;
                /*@editable*/ text-align:center;
            }
            /**
            * @tab Footer
            * @section footer link
            * @tip Set the styling for your email's footer links. Choose a color that helps them stand out from your text.
            */
            .footerContent a:link, .footerContent a:visited, /* Yahoo! Mail Override */ .footerContent a .yshortcuts, .footerContent a span /* Yahoo! Mail Override */{
                /*@editable*/ color:#ffffff;
                /*@editable*/ font-weight:normal;
                /*@editable*/ text-decoration:underline;
            }
            .bold { font-weight: 700; }
            .italics { font-style: italic; }
            .text-center {text-align: center;}
            /* /\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/ MOBILE STYLES /\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/ */
            @media only screen and (max-width: 480px){
                /* /\/\/\/\/\/\/ CLIENT-SPECIFIC MOBILE STYLES /\/\/\/\/\/\/ */
                body, table, td, p, a, li, blockquote{-webkit-text-size-adjust:none !important;} /* Prevent Webkit platforms from changing default text sizes */
                body{width:100% !important; min-width:100% !important;} /* Prevent iOS Mail from adding padding to the body */
                /* /\/\/\/\/\/\/ MOBILE RESET STYLES /\/\/\/\/\/\/ */
                #bodyCell{padding:10px !important;}
                /* /\/\/\/\/\/\/ MOBILE TEMPLATE STYLES /\/\/\/\/\/\/ */
                /* ======== Page Styles ======== */
                /**
                * @tab Mobile Styles
                * @section template width
                * @tip Make the template fluid for portrait or landscape view adaptability. If a fluid layout doesn't work for you, set the width to 300px instead.
                */
                #templateContainer{
                    max-width:600px !important;
                    /*@editable*/ width:100% !important;
                }
                /**
                * @tab Mobile Styles
                * @section heading 1
                * @tip Make the first-level headings larger in size for better readability on small screens.
                */
                h1{
                    /*@editable*/ font-size:24px !important;
                    /*@editable*/ line-height:100% !important;
                }
                /**
                * @tab Mobile Styles
                * @section heading 2
                * @tip Make the second-level headings larger in size for better readability on small screens.
                */
                h2{
                    /*@editable*/ font-size:20px !important;
                    /*@editable*/ line-height:100% !important;
                }
                /**
                * @tab Mobile Styles
                * @section heading 3
                * @tip Make the third-level headings larger in size for better readability on small screens.
                */
                h3{
                    /*@editable*/ font-size:18px !important;
                    /*@editable*/ line-height:100% !important;
                }
                /**
                * @tab Mobile Styles
                * @section heading 4
                * @tip Make the fourth-level headings larger in size for better readability on small screens.
                */
                h4{
                    /*@editable*/ font-size:16px !important;
                    /*@editable*/ line-height:100% !important;
                }
                /* ======== Header Styles ======== */
                #templatePreheader{display:none !important;} /* Hide the template preheader to save space */
                /**
                * @tab Mobile Styles
                * @section header image
                * @tip Make the main header image fluid for portrait or landscape view adaptability, and set the image's original width as the max-width. If a fluid setting doesn't work, set the image width to half its original size instead.
                */
                #headerImage{
                    height:auto !important;
                    /*@editable*/ max-width:600px !important;
                    /*@editable*/ width:100% !important;
                }
                /**
                * @tab Mobile Styles
                * @section header text
                * @tip Make the header content text larger in size for better readability on small screens. We recommend a font size of at least 16px.
                */
                .headerContent{
                    /*@editable*/ font-size:20px !important;
                    /*@editable*/ line-height:125% !important;
                }
                /* ======== Body Styles ======== */
                /**
                * @tab Mobile Styles
                * @section body text
                * @tip Make the body content text larger in size for better readability on small screens. We recommend a font size of at least 16px.
                */
                .bodyContent{
                    /*@editable*/ font-size:18px !important;
                    /*@editable*/ line-height:125% !important;
                }
                /* ======== Footer Styles ======== */
                /**
                * @tab Mobile Styles
                * @section footer text
                * @tip Make the body content text larger in size for better readability on small screens.
                */
                .footerContent{
                    /*@editable*/ font-size:14px !important;
                    /*@editable*/ line-height:115% !important;
                }
                .footerContent a{display:block !important;} /* Place footer social and utility links on their own lines, for easier access */
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body leftmargin="0" marginwidth="0" topmargin="0" marginheight="0" offset="0">
        <center>
            <table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" height="100%" width="100%" id="bodyTable">
                <tr>
                    <td align="center" valign="top" id="bodyCell">
                        <!-- BEGIN TEMPLATE // -->
                        <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" id="templateContainer">
                            <tr>
                                <td align="center" valign="top">
                                    <!-- BEGIN PREHEADER // -->
                                    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" id="templatePreheader">
                                        <tr>
                                            <td width="15%"></td>
                                            <td valign="top" class="preheaderContent" style="padding-top:45px; padding-right:30px; padding-bottom:45px; padding-left:20px;" mc:edit="preheader_content00">
                                                <a href="https://www.s---ce.com"><img src="https://cdn.salesjet.io/660/images/a7f81a58-373e-47ba-8e88-d54cb53884af.png" alt=" Logo"></a>
                                            </td>
                                            <td width="15%"></td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </table>
                                    <!-- // END PREHEADER -->
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td align="center" valign="top">
                                    <!-- BEGIN BODY // -->
                                    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" id="templateBody">
                                        <tr>
                                            <td valign="top" class="bodyContent" mc:edit="body_content">

                                                <p class="container__paragraph">Dear #Contact | First Name#,</p>
                                                <p class="container__paragraph">Wishing you a happy Thanksgiving from us here at ---!</p>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </table>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td align="center" valign="top">
                                    <!-- BEGIN HEADER // -->
                                    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" id="templateHeader">
                                        <tr>
                                            <td valign="top" class="headerContent">
                                                <img src="https://cdn.salesjet.io/660/images/9f4e59f9-f5a9-4194-97c1-053d5b4afc2e.png" style="max-width:600px;" id="headerImage" mc:label="header_image" mc:edit="header_image" mc:allowdesigner mc:allowtext />
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </table>
                                    <!-- // END HEADER -->
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td align="center" valign="top">
                                    <!-- BEGIN BODY // -->
                                    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" id="templateBody">
                                        <tr>
                                            <td valign="top" class="bodyContent" mc:edit="body_content">

                                                <p class="container__paragraph">Time for hot chocolate, warm cider, gingerbread cookies, dreidels, gold chocolate coins and more!</p>

                                                <p class="container__paragraph">Holidays give you that warm, fuzzy feeling, right? Well we are here to do the same!</p>

                                                    <p class="container__paragraph">The holidays are a time of giving and being thankful for all that you have. Want to brighten someone’s day? Share this quote with your friends and family, to show your loved ones you are thinking about them, or even on social media.</p>

                                                    <p class="container__paragraph">Spread joy and cheer, doctor’s orders.</p>

                                                    <p class="container__paragraph">Your Cheerleaders,<br>
                                                    ---</p>                                 



                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </table>
                                    <!-- // END BODY -->
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                    <td align="center" valign="top">
                                        <!-- BEGIN PREHEADER // -->
                                        <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" id="templatePreheader">
                                            <tr>
                                                <td width="15%"></td>
                                                <td width="70%" align="center" valign="top" class="preheaderContent"  style="text-align: center; padding-top:45px; padding-right:30px; padding-bottom:45px; padding-left:20px;" mc:edit="preheader_content00">
                                                    <a href="https://www.---com"><img src="https://cdn.salesjet.io/660/images/a7f81a58-373e-47ba-8e88-d54cb53884af.png" style="" alt="Smile --- Logo"></a>
                                                </td>
                                                <td width="15%"></td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </table>
                                        <!-- // END PREHEADER -->
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td align="center" valign="top">
                                    <!-- BEGIN FOOTER // -->
                                    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" id="templateFooter">
                                        <tr>
                                            <td align="center" valign="top" class="footerContent" style="padding-top:30px;" mc:edit="footer_content02">
                                                <a href="https://---/"><img src="https://cdn.salesjet.io/660/images/d897922a-a973-45d7-9685-7ddb039eaf69.png"></img></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="https://www.instagram.com/"><img src="https://cdn.salesjet.io/660/images/c0152907-5f9c-4e02-a4c6-e574cdf3baa7.png"></img></a>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td align="center" valign="top" class="footerContent" style="padding-top:0;" mc:edit="footer_content02">
                                                &copy; 2020. ---. All Rights Reserved.
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td align="center" valign="top" class="footerContent" style="padding-top:0;" mc:edit="footer_content02">
                                                <p> <a href="https://www.---.com/">https://www.---.com/</a></p><p> --- - ✉ <a href="mailto:info@---e.com">info@sm---e.com</a></p>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td align="center" valign="top" class="footerContent" style="padding-top:0;" mc:edit="footer_content02">
                                                1114 E BROADWAY, Glendale, CA, USA
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>

                                        <tr>
                                            <td align="center" valign="top" class="footerContent" style="padding-top:0;" mc:edit="footer_content02">
                                                <div style="font-size: .5rem;">Icons made by <a href="https://www.flaticon.com/authors/freepik" title="Freepik">Freepik</a> from <a href="https://www.flaticon.com/" title="Flaticon">www.flaticon.com</a></div>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </table>
                                    <!-- // END FOOTER -->
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                        <!-- // END TEMPLATE -->
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </center>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I replicated the issue in Litmus. The email isn't sticking to the 600px width and that's simply down to Gmail not having any CSS to tell it to do that.

Been a while since I've seen any info or updates on this as I inline by default but as far as I'm aware, Webmail Gmail still does not respect CSS in the head. 
**You will need to inline your CSS.**

There are online tools that can do this for you. I would do this and then see how it works.

Comment: omg so painful! I’ll try that, do you have any tool you favor?

Comment: You mentioned that you use Mailchimp. Here is a Link on how to activate the included CSS-Inliner from Mailchimp. I Hope this helps. https://mailchimp.com/help/use-the-css-inliner/

Comment: Thanks I've used another tool and it handled the gmail issue without breaking Outlook. Thanks a lot for the suggestion! :)