# Mailchimp buttons render badly in Gmail using incline CSS

Tags: button, gmail, html-email, mailchimp

I found this SO question and answer that solved a lot of problems for me with getting Mailchimp HTML template emails to render well in Gmail: [Gmail formatting on html template is getting screwed up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59653465/gmail-formatting-on-html-template-is-getting-screwed-up/59660103#59660103)

While this answer solved most of my problems for me, it also introduced a new one: My HTML buttons now render very poorly in Gmail with inline Mailchimp CSS enabled. Previously they previously looked great in Gmail with inline disabled (although a bunch of other things were broken).

They render fine in Apple mail both with and without inline CSS enabled.

Gmail HTML button screenshot

[image]

Apple Mail HTML button screenshot

[image]

What can I do to improve these buttons in Gmail with inline CSS?

Comment: Hi Richard, can you please supply the code for your button and the code being inlined? As much as you can safely share would be preferable.

Comment: Can't seem to attach a file to this post? It is too large to paste in as code snippet. I will email it to you @Digital_Frankenstein. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue and it's a really easy one.

This line here:

```
<td class="mcnButtonContent" style="font-family:Arial, &quot;helvetica neue&quot;:;, helvetica, sans-serif:;font-size:14px;padding:20px;mso-line-height-rule:exactly;-ms-text-size-adjust:100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust:100%;" valign="middle" align="center">
```

Specifically:

```
font-family:Arial, &quot;helvetica neue&quot;:;, helvetica, sans-serif:;
```

You've declared semi-colons in the middle of a font declaration. Then, when you declare another font fallback, Helvetica, the CSS property is broken which in turn breaks the rendering output of the styles.

When I removed those and tested again in Litmus, the button rendered as expected.
I should also note, this was affecting Outlook.com and Office 365 as well.

Basically, it should look like this:

```
<td class="mcnButtonContent" style="font-family:Arial, 'helvetica neue', helvetica, sans-serif;font-size:14px;padding:20px;mso-line-height-rule:exactly;-ms-text-size-adjust:100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust:100%;" valign="middle" align="center">
```

Again, a look at the detail:

```
font-family:Arial, 'helvetica neue', helvetica, sans-serif;
```

You're actually fine to use `&quot;` in place of the actual punctuation. That didn't cause any issues, at least in this small test.

I hope that makes sense! Let me know if not.

Comment: thanks for this. All my template code was 100% generated by Mailchimp so I'm unsure why it's using semicolon in font declarations. Will report that to Mailchimp to see what they can do to eliminate this in future